# Conversion between custom iterator and custom constant iterator

Tags: c++, iterator

I am working on generic two-dimensional container with custom iterators. 
Now I am trying to have one `begin()` and one `end()` function for both my `iterator` and `constant_iterator` type.

My custom iterator is inside my template `Matrix` class (but I put them here separately for the sake of the clarity).

```
template <class T>
class Matrix {

#pragma mark PUBLIC TYPEDEFS
public:
    typedef T value_type;
    typedef std::size_t size_type;
    //typedef typename T::size_type size_type;
    //typedef T::size_type size_type;

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark PRIVATE TYPEDEFS
private:
    typedef T* pointer_type;
    typedef T** storage_type;

   #pragma mark -
#pragma mark PRIVATE VARIABLES
private:
    size_type width_;
    size_type height_;
    storage_type data_;



    // private iterators
    Iterator<T*, T> m_iterator_;
    Iterator<const T*, const T> m_const_iterator_;

    H_Iterator<T*, T> m_hiterator_;
    H_Iterator<const T*, const T> m_const_hiterator_;

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark PUBLIC VARIABLES & TYPEDEFS
public:
    typedef Iterator<T*, T> iterator_type;
    typedef Iterator<const T*, const T> const_iterator_type;

    typedef H_Iterator<T*, T> hiterator;
    typedef H_Iterator<const T*, const T> const_hiterator;

    #pragma mark -
#pragma mark CONSTRUCTORS & DESTRUCTORS
public:
    explicit Matrix(const std::string& fileName) {

    }

    Matrix(const size_type& width, const size_type& height) :   width_(width),
                                                                height_(height),
                                                                data_(CreateMatrix(width, height)),
                                                                m_iterator_(*data_, width, height),
                                                                m_const_iterator_(*data_, width, height),
                                                                m_hiterator_(*data_, width, height),
                                                                m_const_hiterator_(*data_, width, height),                                                                    

        // fill the created matrix with default values of "T"
        for (Matrix<T>::iterator_type it = this->begin(); it != this->end(); ++it)
            *it = T();
    }

    ~Matrix() {
        delete [] data_[0]; // because in data_[0] is array of value_type
        delete [] data_;
    }

    #pragma mark -
#pragma mark PRIVATE METHODS
private:
    storage_type CreateMatrix(const size_type width, const size_type height) {
        storage_type d = new pointer_type[height]; // array with pointers pointing to rows inside the "block"
        pointer_type block = new value_type[width * height]; // one block of memory to store the data

        for (size_type row = 0; row < height; ++row)
            d[row] = &block[row * width];

        return d;
    }

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark PUBLIC METHODS
public:
    hiterator h_begin(size_type row) { return m_hiterator_.begin(row); }
    hiterator h_end(size_type row) { return m_hiterator_.end(row); }
    const_hiterator ch_begin(size_type row) { return m_const_hiterator_.begin(row); }
    const_hiterator ch_end(size_type row) { return m_const_hiterator_.end(row); }
```

And my inner `Iterator` class + derived `H_Iterator` class (`H_Iterator` class is for looping through one row of matrix from left to right)

```
#pragma mark ITERATOR CLASSES
template <typename P, typename V> // "P" - PointerType; "V" - ValueType
class Iterator : public std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, T> {
protected:
    P itData_;
    size_type w_; // width of the matrix
    size_type h_; // height of the matrix
public:
    Iterator(P d, size_type width, size_type height) : itData_(d), w_(width), h_(height) { }
    Iterator() { }
public:
    V& operator*() const {
        return *itData_;
    }
    Iterator<P, V>& operator++() {
        ++itData_;
        return *this;
    }
    Iterator<P, V>& operator= (T value) {
        *itData_ = value;
        return *this;
    }
    P operator->() {
        return itData_;
    }
    friend bool operator==(const Iterator& lhs, const Iterator& rhs) {
        return !(lhs.itData_ != rhs.itData_);
    }
    friend bool operator!=(const Iterator& lhs, const Iterator& rhs) {
        return !(lhs.itData_ == rhs.itData_);
    }

    Iterator<P, V> begin() { return Iterator<P, V>(itData_, w_, h_); }
    Iterator<P, V> end() { return Iterator<P, V>(itData_ + w_ * h_, w_, h_); };
};

template <typename P, typename V> // "P" - PointerType; "V" - ValueType
class H_Iterator : public Iterator<P, V> {
public:
    H_Iterator(P d, size_type width, size_type height) : Iterator<P, V>(d, width, height) { }
    H_Iterator() { }
public:
    H_Iterator<P, V> begin(size_type row) { return H_Iterator<P, V>(this->itData_ + this->w_ * row, this->w_, this->h_); }
    H_Iterator<P, V> end(size_type row) { return H_Iterator<P, V>(this->itData_ + this->w_ * row + this->w_, this->w_, this->h_); };
};
```

Currently if I want to loop through one of the rows using constant iterator I must do it like this (=I must use `begin` and `end` function that was made specifically for `constant_hiterator` - `ch_begin()` and `ch_end()`):

```
Matrix<int> m (5, 5);
for (Matrix<int>::const_hiterator hit = m.ch_begin(row); hit != m.ch_end(row); ++hit) {
    cout << *hit << " ";
}
```

I am struggling to have only one `begin()` and `end()` function for both my `const_hiterator` and `hiterator`. So I can write iterators code similarly like iterators for std::vector:

```
std::vector<int> vector;
for (std::vector<int>::const_iterator it = vector.begin(); it != vector.end(); ++it) { }
for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = vector.begin(); it != vector.end(); ++it) { }
```

I assume that I should have some type of conversion between `hiterator` and `const_hiterator`.

Comment: Side note: Having no sparse matrix, a one dimensional array of size N*M makes the matrix implementation much easier.

Comment: Also, you should get the matrix class right, first. (The destructor is most certainly wrong)

Comment: I am sorry I am not sure what do you mean. I edited my `Matrix` class code (added `CreateMatrix()` function) so you can see how I represent my data in memory if that is what you mean.

Comment: Ignore the comments above, but your memory model is too complicated. Drop the array of rows (storage_type) and just have an array N*M and maybe an operator T () (size_type row, size_type column) and no operator [].

Comment: @Superian007 -- What Dieter Lücking is referring to is to have your matrix internally be represented by a one dimensional array of size N*M. This has a number of advantages. It ensures that the data are compact and contiguous, which is very good for modern computers with multiple cache levels, particularly so with small matrices. It makes it easier to do slicing and dicing of your array. A data/view model (e.g., Blitz++, Eigen) is a nicer approach for multi-dimensioned arrays than is an STL-iterator model.

Comment: @DieterLücking Why is using operator considered `[]` a bad approach?

Comment: Having a two dimensional matrix and operator [] you implement the matrix in terms of convenience (which is actually a habit of accessing a two dimensional array), instead of having efficient access (which I consider more important). Although you could use some proxy for matrix[][], I do not think it is worth anything.,

Comment: Saying this I think I will eventually rewrite it, thank you. Could you also please take a look at my original question?

Comment: Having contiguous memory and row mayor order: typedef T* iterator (column mayor needs an iterator implementation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some heavy head-winds that throw a few monkey wrenches here. Actually, it is common for custom containers to have separate begin() and end() iterators for mutable and constant iterators for one very simple reason, best demonstrated by the following example. This example demonstrates the typical container/iterator semantics that the C++ library implements, and is generally desired for custom container/iterators to implement the same way:

```
class CustomContainer {

public:

     class const_iterator {

        // ...

     };

     class iterator : public const_iterator {

        // ...
     };

     iterator begin();
     iterator end();

     const_iterator begin() const;
     const_iterator end() const;
};
```

The standard container/iterator semantics don't use separate begin() and end() methods for mutable and constant iterators. Rather, object.begin(), or pointer->begin() ends up invoking either the constant or the mutable version of begin() depending upon whether `object` or `pointer` is a reference/pointer to a mutable or a `const` instance of the class.

In summary:

1) A mutable iterator begin()/end() methods get called for mutable instances of the class.

2) A begin()/end() on a const instance of a class can only return the constant iterator type. If your begin()/end() operator would return mutable iterators when invoked on a const class instance, then this makes it possible to modify a const instance of the class by simply instantiating its mutable iterators!

3) It is strongly desired for a mutable iterator to be a subclass of the const iterator. This is the easiest way to automatically support passing a mutable iterator to a function or a method that only requires a const iterator parameter (it is also possible to implement that by defining and implementing an overload cast operator, but using subclasses is much easier, and typically results in better performance).

Now, certainly it would be convenient to have a single begin()/end() implementation. And it's not like there's legal requirement that mandates one to always properly support the typical iterator semantics.

But, correctly supporting these expected iterator semantics makes it much easier to leverage all the algorithms in the C++ library, and have them work correctly, with no surprises.

It is certainly possible to declare both mutable and constant begin() and end() methods as wrappers around a private factory that produces a mutable beginning or an ending iterator, with the constant begin()/end() facades degrading it to a constant iterator before returning it. That would be one possible approach. It's not ideal, since the private factory has to be a constant method, in order for it to be invokable from the constant begin()/end() wrappers.